# angularJS resolve: in controller "Cannot read property 'goals' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal, ui.bootstrap

This is my first question on stackoverflow. ( I know I struggled a lot with the quotes..)   I am stuck with this problem where a snippet of the following code leaves me with the following error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'goals' of undefined
>      at $scope.addValue.$modal.open.resolve.goals (app.js:59)
>      at Object.invoke (angular.js:3762)
>      at ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.12.1.js:2118
>      at Object.forEach (angular.js:329)
>      at getResolvePromises (ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.12.1.js:2116)
>      at Object.$modalProvider.$get.$modal.open (ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.12.1.js:2151)
>      at Scope.$scope.addValue (app.js:53)
>      at Parser.functionCall (angular.js:10294)
>      at angular.js:18229
>      at Scope.$get.Scope.$eval (angular.js:12075)

'goals' in my code is the equivalent of 'items' in the 'inspired by" code.

This message seems to come from the ctrlAddValue controller which includes 'goals' reference:   function($scope, $modalInstance, goals)

Thanks for any help!

THe culprit:

```
app.controller("ctrlCtx", function ($scope, $state, $stateParams, $modal,     $window) {

$scope.goals = "A good goal";

     $scope.addValue = function (size, $scope) {
        var modalInstance = $modal.open({
            templateUrl: 'templates/addValue.html',
            size: "lg",
            controller: "ctrlAddValue",
            resolve: {
                goals: function () {
                    return $scope.goals;
                }
            }
        })
        modalInstance.result.then(
             function (selectedItem) {

              }, 
              function () {

              });
     }; });
```

This is the 'ctrlAddValue' controller code.

```
app.controller('ctrlAddValue', function ($scope, $state, $modalInstance, goals) {

$scope.addValue = function(){

    $modalInstance.close();
};

$scope.cancel = function () {
    $modalInstance.dismiss();
 };

 });
```

This is based on the ui.bootstrap demo for modal.

Comment: Where is the ctrlAddValue?

Comment: where code is inspired from is not relevant, where's the actual controller code? The other code looks like exact code from demos of angular-ui

Comment: @Fals I just added ctrlAddValue.

Comment: @charlietfl, I removed the demo code as suggested and added the controller code.   Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
app.controller("ctrlCtx", function ($scope, $state, $stateParams, $modal,     $window) {

$scope.goals = "A good goal";

     $scope.addValue = function (size, $scope) {
```

you are passing $scope as a local parameter and probably calling this function like $scope.addValue(something); making the local $scope undefined.

remove the $scope parameter from your addValue function.

Answer (score 0):

Set yout ctrlCtx to look like this:

```
 app.controller("ctrlCtx", function ($scope, $state, $stateParams, $modal,     $window) {

        $scope.goals = "A good goal";

             $scope.addValue = function () {
                var modalInstance = $modal.open({
                    templateUrl: 'templates/addValue.html',
                    size: "lg",
                    controller: "ctrlAddValue",
                    resolve: {
                        goals: function () {
                            return $scope.goals;
                        }
                    }
                })

             }; 
        });
```

After that goals should be available in ctrlAddValue